# Logback - filtering stack trace

Tags: java, stack-trace, logback

I'm using logback for logging and i found some problem with filtering stack trace.
I hava a structure like this:

```
public class Main {
    static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("Start");

        MyObject1 loggingElement = new MyObject1();
        loggingElement.logg();

        logger.debug("End");
    }
}


public class MyObject1 {

    public MyObject2 obj;
    static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyObject1.class);

    public MyObject1() {
        obj = new MyObject2();
    }
    public void logg() {
        obj.loggError();
    }
}
public class MyObject2 {
    static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyObject2.class);

    public void loggError() {
        logger.error("Error info", new Throwable("Error"));
    }
}
```

and configuration xml like this:

```
<property name="mask" 
            value="MyObject2"/>


<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} | %level | %-4thread | %-21logger | %m%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="${root.level:-TRACE}">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

When i run the main method i get output like this:

```
12:29:35 | DEBUG | main | com.logging.Main      | Start
12:29:35 | ERROR | main | com.logging.MyObject2 | Error info
java.lang.Throwable: Error
    at com.logging.MyObject2.loggError(MyObject2.java:11) [bin/:na]
    at com.logging.MyObject1.logg(MyObject1.java:17) [bin/:na]
    at com.logging.Main.main(Main.java:14) [bin/:na]
12:29:35 | DEBUG | main | com.logging.Main      | End
```

i would like to remove line with 'MyObject1' in it and leave rest of stack trace untouched just like int this example:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/filtering-stack-trace-hell

i tried to change configuration of logback

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} | %level | %-4thread | %-21logger | %m%n%ex{full,${mask}}
</pattern>
```

doesn't work at all

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} | %level | %-4thread | %-21logger | %m%n%eXe{full,${mask}}
            </pattern>
```

removes whole stack trace(not solution for me)

Anyone knows anything that could help?

Comment: Are you using the fork mentioned in the article or the standard logback jar. Logback does not yet support this feature, see open ticket [here](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-540)

Comment: ;/ im not realy interested in fork ,but your answer clears my confusion, thanks

Answer (score 6):

This capability has been [included in Logback Classic as of version 1.1.3](http://logback.qos.ch/news.html). It seems to apply to the following Conversion Words of PatternLayout:

- [ex / exception / throwable](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ex)
- [rEx / rootException](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#rootException)
- [xEx / xException / xThrowable](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#xThrowable)

Answer (score 2):

On my case I used a [`ThrowableConverter`](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/master/src/main/java/net/logstash/logback/stacktrace/ShortenedThrowableConverter.java) for the stacktrace.

You can add that to your logback.xml where you have your consoleApender, inside your encoder:

```xml
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">

            <!-- your other encoder configurations -->

            <stackTrace>
                <fieldName>stacktrace</fieldName>
                <throwableConverter class="net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter">
                    <pattern>[%thread] - %msg%n%stack{1,1024,10,rootFirst}</pattern>
                </throwableConverter>
            </stackTrace>

        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

It will add a field name *"stack_trace"* with the stack trace. And it does the job for me.

Inside stack you have the parameters:

- **maxDepthPerThrowable**: Limits the number of stackTraceElements per throwable
- **maxLength**: Limits the total length in characters of the trace.
- **shortenedClassNameLength**: Abbreviates class names based on the `shortenedClassName`
- **rootCauseFirst**: Outputs in either 'normal' order (root-cause-last), or root-cause-first