# Springboot stack-trace logging filter only from my packages

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, stack-trace

I'm using Springboot with the sl4j-api 1.7.2.

Is there a way to filter out from stack-traces only the lines starting with my packages, or excluding from the log file lines coming from spring framework or other libraries that I use.

This would simplify reading the log file, and reduce enormously the space required for log files. In more than 99% of the cases, the errors are in my code, not in the libs I use.

I wanted to see if there are any consolidated solutions before embarking in my onw, home made remedies.

Eg. This 30+ lines long stack-trace

```
2020-12-18 03:59:40,179 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] ERROR RestCommunicatorImpl - sort
com.my.package.exception.AlreadyRunningException: Already running
    at com.my.package.impl.RestCommunicatorImpl.validate(RestCommunicatorImpl.java:244) ~[classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.my.package.impl.RestCommunicatorImpl.spawn(RestCommunicatorImpl.java:200) ~[classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.my.package.impl.RestOrchestratorImpl.onAction(RestCommunicatorImpl.java:819) ~[classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.my.package.impl.RestCommunicatorImpl.sort(RestCommunicatorImpl.java:561) ~[classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.my.package.impl.RestCommunicatorImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$db5641d3.invoke(<generated>) [classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ge.og.rmd.analytics.kernel.boot.orchestrator.impl.RestOrchestratorImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f68bccb1.sortRuntime(<generated>) [classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.ge.og.rmd.analytics.kernel.boot.amqp.consumer.ConsumerManager.processCommandOutMessage(ConsumerManager.java:622) [classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor268.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180) [spring-messaging-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112) [spring-messaging-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:126) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:106) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:822) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:745) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1276) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:726) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1219) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1189) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) [spring-rabbit-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
```

Sould be 7 rows

```
2020-12-18 03:59:40,179 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] ERROR RestCommunicatorImpl - sort
com.my.package.exception.AlreadyRunningException: Already running
    at com.my.package.impl.RestCommunicatorImpl.validate(RestCommunicatorImpl.java:244) ~[classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.my.package.impl.RestCommunicatorImpl.spawn(RestCommunicatorImpl.java:200) ~[classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.my.package.impl.RestOrchestratorImpl.onAction(RestCommunicatorImpl.java:819) ~[classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.my.package.impl.RestCommunicatorImpl.sort(RestCommunicatorImpl.java:561) ~[classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.my.package.impl.RestCommunicatorImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$db5641d3.invoke(<generated>) [classes!/:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use AspectJ to intercept invocations of `log.error()` and modifying log entry. Or you can implement custom [TurboFilter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#TurboFilter)(Logback is required) for same interception

Answer (score 2):

There is an Open source library MgntUtils (written by me) that does exactly what you are asking - smart stacktrace filtering. Here is Javadoc for [TextUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html) Class

All you will you will have to do is this:

```
try {
...
} catch(Exception e) {
  logger.info("your message {}", TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, true, "com.my.package.");
}
```

Also if you anywhere in your code will invoke just once `TextUtils.setRelevantPackage("com.my.package.");` than instead of using `TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, true, "com.my.package.");` you can just use `TextUtils.getStacktrace(e);`. All the versions of the method `TextUtils.getStacktrace(...)` return stacktrace as a string that may be filtered or unfiltered. You can get the library as [maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) or on the [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) including source code and Javadoc. You can read an article describing the library here: [MgntUtils Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing, Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/). Note that the article describes most but not all features of the library

Comment: This is great Michael, thanks! Nevertheless, let me see if there are any solutions out there that don't involve using further libs, before I accept yours.

Comment: Obviously, you can look. But I searched before, and there are only IDE tools that allow you to filter stacktrace for display purposes in IDE. I did see some other solutions similar to mine, but not as library that could be used out of the box. As for my library, I used this filtering utils in many projects including in the ones that ran in production for many years. At least since 2012 (way before it was published as library) I also know that some other companies used this library for that purpose as well. So, this code is battle tested and very reliable. It is also simple to use

Comment: Also, you can use article I wrote about this library (with some comments of the users) here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/

Answer (score 2):

For maintenance purpose, a better practice is to let the code as is, and to perform the filtering using the logger.
This also reduces the number of required dependencies as compared to Michael Gantman solution.

Logback for instance has such a feature that you can configure in your logback.xml file with "%rEx{}"

Relevant SO resource: [Logback - filtering stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559477/logback-filtering-stack-trace)